# Take screenshot of React app and generate it as PDF

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf-generation, screenshot

I'd like to generate a PDF from my React App, the easiest way would probably be to take a screenshot of the current state of my app / ideally a div and save it as PDF...I just don't seem to be able to find the best way how to do it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone reading this pdfkit can also generate pdfs in the browser...nice!

You'll need to check out pdfkit website and specifically I only got it to work using the browser releases for pdfkit and blob-stream

https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit/releases
https://github.com/devongovett/blob-stream/releases

My code looked like

```
import PDFDocument from 'pdfkit'
import BlobStream from 'blob-stream'
import FileSaver from 'file-saver'

let doc = new PDFDocument()
    let stream = doc.pipe(BlobStream())
    addHeader(doc, 'My Report.....')
    doc.moveDown(0.5).fontSize(8)
   // render you doc
   // then add a stream eventListener to allow download
stream.on('finish', ()=>{
      let blob = stream.toBlob('application/pdf')
      FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'myPDF.pdf')

    })
    doc.end()
```

Comment: In the context of a react app (think react-router-dom route page), what happens for in "render your doc"?

Comment: How do you download the "browser releases" of pdfkit and blob-stream?

Answer (score 1):

How about a combination of:

html2canvas: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

and

jsPDF: https://parall.ax/products/jspdf

From the canvas provided by html2canvas, you can convert it to an image with .toDataUrl() and then feed that into jsPDF with the .addImage() method which wants a base64 image.

Comment: that sounds like a good idea...just not sure how to include libraries as such into my reactjs app...bit of a newbie :)

Comment: No problem, 

If you are using webpack both are available on npm: [html2canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2canvas) [jspdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf)

If you are just including React on the page both have CDN links on the links above.

Comment: I just posted a detailed answer about the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45017234/1587695). Hope it helps.

Comment: There is a problem with jsPDF wich I bumped into. The addImage method do its stuff in sync manner and the whole app just hangs. And it can't be moved into web worker because it relies on the DOM. It's not very user-friendly. So I used html2canvas on the client and pdfkit on the backend to solve the similar task. It's pretty much pain in the ass in either case though.

Answer (score 0):

Using [html2canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2canvas) and [jsPDF](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf) created a react components that export the div and its children components as pdf and Image

The react component is defined as following

```
        import React from 'react'
        import html2canvas from 'html2canvas'
        import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";
    
        class Exporter extends React.Component {
           constructor(props) {
             super(props)
           } 
    
        export =(type, name)=>{
    
        html2canvas(document.querySelector(`#capture`)).then(canvas => {
          let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    
          if (type === 'pdf') {
            const pdf = new jsPDF({
              orientation: "landscape",
              unit: "in",
              format: [14, 10]
            });
    
            pdf.addImage(dataURL, 'PNG', .6, .6);
            pdf.save(`${name}.pdf`);
    
          } else if (type === 'png') {
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.download = `${name}.png`;
            link.href = dataURL;
            link.click();
          }
        });
     }
     render() { 
        return (
          <div>
            <button onClick={()=>this.export("pdf", "my-content")}></button>
            <div id={`capture`} >
              Content to export as pdf/png
              {this.props.children} //any child Component render here will be exported as pdf/png
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

export default Exporter
```