# Generating a PDF file from React Components

Tags: reactjs, pdf, meteor

I have been building a polling application. People are able to create their polls and get data regarding the question(s) they ask. I would like to add the functionality to let the users download the results in the form of a PDF.

For example I have two components which are responsible for grabbing the question and data.

```
<QuestionBox />
<ViewCharts />
```

I'm attempting to output both components into a PDF file. The user can then download this PFD file. I have found a few packages that permit the rendering of a PDF inside a component. However I failed to find one that can generate PDF from an input stream consisting of a virtual DOM. If I want to achieve this from scratch what approach should I follow ?

Comment: Based on this question and the answers, I wrote two brief tutorials about this topic: [React Component to PDF](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-component-to-pdf) & [React Component to Image](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-component-to-image)

Comment: @RobinWieruch Great article, but what if the component is big enough it doesn't fit on one page? I have just followed your tutorial , yet if there is a moderate amount of content it doesn't show all of it .  Do you maybe know how to make a 'break' and start a new page ? Thanks !

Comment: @PeterMalik maybe you could try landscape mode. An alternative could be triggering a CSS media query before generating the image, so that the media query brings the content into a more suitable shape for the PDF.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Rendering react as pdf is generally a pain, but there is a way around it using canvas.

The idea is to convert :
HTML -> Canvas -> PNG (or JPEG) -> PDF

To achieve the above, you'll need :

1. [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com) &
2. [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

```js
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';

// download html2canvas and jsPDF and save the files in app/ext, or somewhere else
// the built versions are directly consumable
// import {html2canvas, jsPDF} from 'app/ext';


export default class Export extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  printDocument() {
    const input = document.getElementById('divToPrint');
    html2canvas(input)
      .then((canvas) => {
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        const pdf = new jsPDF();
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
        // pdf.output('dataurlnewwindow');
        pdf.save("download.pdf");
      })
    ;
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>
      <div className="mb5">
        <button onClick={this.printDocument}>Print</button>
      </div>
      <div id="divToPrint" className="mt4" {...css({
        backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5',
        width: '210mm',
        minHeight: '297mm',
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        marginRight: 'auto'
      })}>
        <div>Note: Here the dimensions of div are same as A4</div> 
        <div>You Can add any component here</div>
      </div>
    </div>);
  }
}
```

The snippet will not work here because the required files are not imported.

An alternate approach is being used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41529149/create-pdf-file-from-html-text-react), where the middle steps are dropped and you can simply convert from HTML to PDF. There is an option to do this in the jsPDF documentation as well, but from personal observation, I feel that better accuracy is achieved when dom is converted into png first.

**Update 0: September 14, 2018**

The text on the pdfs created by this approach will not be selectable. If that's a requirement, you might find [this article](https://blog.usejournal.com/lets-make-a-resume-in-react-2c9c5540f51a) helpful.

Comment: I have successfully created a PDF file from an html page with the help of your answer.

But if we want to create a PDF with multiple pages then what to do? with a4 size page with appropriate margins at all sides and in each new page that margin should be applied.

please help me its argent. Thank you in advance. I have created a question here [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47529365/multipage-pdf-with-html2canvas)

Comment: Same thing. Position your content in a list of divs. Each div represents an a4 sheet (add css to the div to replicate margins). Then run the print function on each div.

Comment: @ShivekKhurana my div changes acording to the size of the screen, but I'd like the PDF file to be always the same, not depending on window size. Is there anyway I can do that? Also, how do i import {...css} ?

Comment: By this method can the text on created pdf be copied ?

Comment: @Goutham the answer is no: the content of the PDF is a bitmap image

Comment: This method is not working if included an image in the div. any solution text along with image?

Comment: This works, but the PDF that is generated appears massively zoomed in to the top-left corner. Any ideas why this might be the case?

Comment: @Matt maybe try setting the dimensions of the parent div in millimeters.

Comment: @ShivekKhurana I'm not sure what you mean. Could this be because I'm on a Mac with a retina screen? Screenshots are always really big because of the resolution...

Comment: You can try this codesandbox that I have created to generate a PDF file from React component:
https://codesandbox.io/s/20qpkznx3p

Comment: super easy and clean solution! thanx @ShivekKhurana :)
(btw i think addImage accepts either 1/8 arguments.)

Comment: @ShivekKhurana how to use above code in react typescript project?

Answer (score 16):

### [React-PDF](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf) is a great resource for this.

It is a bit time consuming converting your markup and CSS to React-PDF's format, but it is easy to understand. Exporting a PDF and from it is fairly straightforward.

To allow a user to download a PDF generated by react-PDF, use their [on the fly rendering](https://react-pdf.org/advanced#on-the-fly-rendering), which provides a customizable download link. When clicked, the site renders and downloads the PDF for the user.

Here's their [REPL](https://react-pdf.org/repl) which will familiarize you with the markup and styling required. They have a download link for the PDF too, but they don't show the code for that here.

Answer (score 12):

Only few steps. We can download or generate PDF from our HTML page or we can generate PDF of specific div from a HTML page.

Steps : HTML -> Image (PNG or JPEG) -> PDF

Please Follow the below steps,

Step 1 :-

```
npm install --save html-to-image
npm install jspdf --save
```

Step 2 :-

```
/* ES6 */
import * as htmlToImage from 'html-to-image';
import { toPng, toJpeg, toBlob, toPixelData, toSvg } from 'html-to-image';
 
/* ES5 */
var htmlToImage = require('html-to-image');

-------------------------
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";
```

Step 3 :-

```
   ******  With out PDF properties given below  ******

 htmlToImage.toPng(document.getElementById('myPage'), { quality: 0.95 })
        .then(function (dataUrl) {
          var link = document.createElement('a');
          link.download = 'my-image-name.jpeg';
          const pdf = new jsPDF();          
          pdf.addImage(dataUrl, 'PNG', 0, 0);
          pdf.save("download.pdf"); 
        });


    ******  With PDF properties given below ******

    htmlToImage.toPng(document.getElementById('myPage'), { quality: 0.95 })
        .then(function (dataUrl) {
          var link = document.createElement('a');
          link.download = 'my-image-name.jpeg';
          const pdf = new jsPDF();
          const imgProps= pdf.getImageProperties(dataUrl);
          const pdfWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
          const pdfHeight = (imgProps.height * pdfWidth) / imgProps.width;
          pdf.addImage(dataUrl, 'PNG', 0, 0,pdfWidth, pdfHeight);
          pdf.save("download.pdf"); 
        });
```

I think this is helpful. Please try

Comment: Is the link and link.download necessary?

Comment: not needed though

Comment: this worked for me very easily

Comment: It is not accommodating full page, crops from the bottom.

Answer (score 11):

you can user canvans with jsPDF

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';

 _exportPdf = () => {

     html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);  // if you want see your screenshot in body.
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        const pdf = new jsPDF();
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0);
        pdf.save("download.pdf"); 
    });

 }
```

and you div with id capture is:

## example

```
<div id="capture">
  <p>Hello in my life</p>
  <span>How can hellp you</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Why did you add a copy of the answer?

Comment: The image quality isn't good, and with a4 side part of the generated Pdf is cut, this result is the same with both react-to-pdf and jdpdf library

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that it will capture the whole image of the div but will generate pdf with part of that - not the complete. specially when the div is too wide. easy fix is to replace two line. one is the jspdf constructor line `const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4', false);` and second will be pasting image on pdf line `pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, 600, 0, undefined, false);`. if you want to adjust the width or height of captured image in pdf then play with 5th parameter of addImage function. Go NUTS :P

Answer (score 7):

```
my opinion : 

import { useRef } from "react";
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";
import html2canvas from "html2canvas";

import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const printDocument = () => {
    html2canvas(inputRef.current).then((canvas) => {
      const imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      const pdf = new jsPDF();
      pdf.addImage(imgData, "JPEG", 0, 0);
      pdf.save("download.pdf");
    });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <div className="mb5">
          <button onClick={printDocument}>Print</button>
        </div>
        <div id="divToPrint" ref={inputRef}>
          <div>Note: Here the dimensions of div are same as A4</div>
          <div>You Can add any component here</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default App;

link demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-sea-44b4q?file=/src/App.js:0-907
```

Comment: This is only capture one page if the component has more than one page!!

Answer (score 6):

Besides using the `html2canvas` and `jspdf` libraries, I found another simple-to-use library called `react-to-print` for downloading a React component as a PDF file here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print.
The documentation, examples, and demos are amazing.
It even has documentation for class-based component and functional-based component users.

Here is a sample of using functional-based component:

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { useReactToPrint } from 'react-to-print';

import { ComponentToPrint } from './ComponentToPrint';

const Example = () => {
  const componentRef = useRef();
  const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
    content: () => componentRef.current,
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <ComponentToPrint ref={componentRef} />
      <button onClick={handlePrint}>Print this out!</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This does not download the component as PDF. It displays a PDF preview for it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use ReactDOMServer to render your component to HTML and then use this on jsPDF.

First do the imports:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
```

then:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.fromHTML(ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(this.render()));
doc.save("myDocument.pdf");
```

Prefer to use:

> renderToStaticMarkup

instead of:

> renderToString

As the former include HTML code that react relies on.

Comment: Looked interesting, but renderToStaticMarkup doesnt return any styling, so as far as I can tell jsPDF simply renders some default layout of the raw html unless there is some way to inject css classes?

Answer (score 3):

This may or may not be a sub-optimal way of doing things, but the simplest solution to the multi-page problem I found was to ensure all rendering is done before calling the jsPDFObj.save method.

As for rendering hidden articles, this is solved with a similar fix to css image text replacement, I position absolutely the element to be rendered -9999px off the page left,
this doesn't affect layout and allows for the elem to be visible to html2pdf, especially when using tabs, accordions and other UI components that depend on `{display: none}`.

This method wraps the prerequisites in a promise and calls `pdf.save()` in the `finally()` method. I cannot be sure that this is foolproof, or an anti-pattern, but it would seem that it works in most cases I have thrown at it.

```js
// Get List of paged elements.
let elems = document.querySelectorAll('.elemClass');
let pdf = new jsPDF("portrait", "mm", "a4");

// Fix Graphics Output by scaling PDF and html2canvas output to 2
pdf.scaleFactor = 2;

// Create a new promise with the loop body
let addPages = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  elems.forEach((elem, idx) => {
    // Scaling fix set scale to 2
    html2canvas(elem, {scale: "2"})
      .then(canvas =>{
        if(idx < elems.length - 1){
          pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"), 0, 0, 210, 297);
          pdf.addPage();
        } else {
          pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"), 0, 0, 210, 297);
          console.log("Reached last page, completing");
        }
  })
  
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, "Timeout adding page #" + idx);
})

addPages.finally(()=>{
   console.log("Saving PDF");
   pdf.save();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
npm install jspdf --save
```

//code on react

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';


var doc = new jsPDF()


 doc.fromHTML("<div>JOmin</div>", 1, 1)


onclick //

 doc.save("name.pdf")
```

Comment: @Felix the HTML string allows for `<style>` tags so you'd have to write CSS inline.

Answer (score 2):

You can use my library [react-pdf-printer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf-printer).

This library will help you have control e.g. customizing size of the page, pointing where your website can be splitted into many pages or setting custom header and footer with pagination.

I hope it helps you are somebody else.

Comment: can you give a small example on how to use it?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, example is linked to github repo
[gh repo](https://github.com/krupinskij/react-pdf-printer-example)
[gh pages](https://krupinskij.github.io/react-pdf-printer-example/)

Answer (score 1):

I used jsPDF and html-to-image.

You can check out the code on the below git repo.

[Link](https://github.com/Vijay-Gaikwad/html-pdf/blob/main/src/App.js)

> If you like, you can drop a star there✌️

Answer (score 0):

You can also try "React on the fly pdf" which will generate pdf from HTML. This plugin uses html2canvas and jspdf under the hood to generate the pdf document. This plugin supports multiple pages, header and footer. I like to warn you that it won't generate "real" pdf. Meaning real pdf should be vector. I can't think of any of Javascript plugin which can generate real pdf. You need to use some other tools to do that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

You can use [ReactPDF](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf)

Lets you convert a div into PDF with ease. You will need to match your existing markup to use ReactPDF markup, but it is worth it.

Comment: This only allows displaying of PDFs not converting DOM to PDFs? Correct me if i'm wrong please

Comment: this doesn't convert it in pdf for download. Its just a viewer.

Comment: ReactPDF is a viewer, it allows displaying PDF on DOM.