# Error - ( Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function) while converting HTML to PDF in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
//need to change it to the accurate data point
class Child extends Component {

  printDocument() {
    const input = document.getElementById('divToPrint');
    console.log(input);

    html2canvas(input).then((canvas) => {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        const pdf = new jsPDF();
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
        pdf.save("download.pdf");
    }).catch(e => console.log(e));
  }

  render() {
    const mrrRecord = this.props.mrr;
    return (
      <html>
        <body>
          <div>
            <div id="divToPrint" className="mt4" {...css({
              backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5',
              width: '210mm',
              minHeight: '297mm',
              marginLeft: 'auto',
              marginRight: 'auto'
            })}>
              Note: Here the dimensions of div are same as A4 You Can add any component here
            </div> 
            <button onClick={this.printDocument}>Print</button>
          </div>
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}
```

**NOTE : Im getting error(Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function () ) on the following when converting html to canvas. I suspect its because input of htmlcanvas is html element and htmltocanvas is not able to convert html into the right format  -

```
html2canvas(input).then((canvas) => {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);**
```

Comment: could anyone help me with this??

Comment: @kometen I had added this question but didnt get any response so i thought i should ask on the same link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44989119/generating-a-pdf-file-from-react-components/47334864#47334864.

Answer (score 3):

- Try installing html2canvas using `npm install --save html2canvas`
- and then importing it into your js file as `import * as html2canvas from 'html2canvas'`.

This worked for me! Hope it helps

Comment: import * as html2canvas from "html2canvas"; is a good solution

Comment: What is the difference between just using `import {html2pdf} from 'html2pdf' ` and `import * as html2canvas from "html2canvas" `