# download a react component as pdf

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

Needed solution in Reactjs
i want to download any component content as a pdf with all the css effect.
need help to complete the downloadAsPdf function

```
import React from 'react'

function downloadAsPdf(component,filename) {
    // todo download the component as pdf with that specified filename
}

function Table() {
    return (
        <div>
            Ant content that i want to download as pdf
        </div>
    )
}

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onclick={downloadAsPdf(Table,"id.pdf")}>download table as PDF </button>
            <p> some other work...</p>
        </div>
    )
}
export default App
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating a PDF file from React Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44989119/generating-a-pdf-file-from-react-components)

Comment: that solution has a bug like it is not able to draw img Tag into canvas or say pdf,

Comment: I just wrote up a tutorial about how to extract a React component as PDF. People can read it over here: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-component-to-image